# How to display an array with the indexes beneath them

Tags: indexing, arrays

I'm trying to draw an array but also have the indexes beneath them. Right now, all I have is this

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (s) at (0,0);
    \foreach \num in {3, 1, 4, 1, 5}{
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] at (s) {\num};
      \coordinate (s) at ($(s) + (1,0)$);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:testArray}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This might give the desired results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{index}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setcounter{index}{0}
    \coordinate (s) at (0,0);
    \foreach \num in {3, 1, 4, 1, 5}{
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] at (s) {\num};
      \node at ($(s)-(0,0.5)$) {\theindex};
      \stepcounter{index}
      \coordinate (s) at ($(s) + (1,0)$);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:testArray}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setcounter{index}{0}
    \coordinate (s) at (0,0);
    \foreach \num in {2, 7, 1, 8, 2}{
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] at (s) {\num};
      \node at ($(s)-(0,0.5)$) {\theindex};
      \stepcounter{index}
      \coordinate (s) at ($(s) + (1,0)$);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:testArray2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
EDIT: I restructured the code a little to be less prone to errors.

Comment: This helps. However, when I used this same code for another figure, I got an error. Can you help with that too please?

Comment: @JoseAcuna I can't if you don't show the code, obviously. And the error message would come in handy, too. You might open another question or edit yours (without removing the original question). If the issue is caused by my code, editing would be fine. If it is by your code, a new question would be better, I guess.

Comment: @JoseAcuna if I had to guess, it's because you reused the line `\newcounter{index}`. The counter is defined globally, so you should only issue the `\newcounter` command once. Instead use `\setcounter{index}{0}`.